# String format to convert datetime causes an error

Tags: c#, datetime, converters, string-formatting

I try to convert `persiandate` to `standard date`.So my persian date has these formats (it means the user can enter these formats :

```
1392/1/1
1392/01/01
1392/01/1
1392/1/01
```

So i write a function to convert my persian date to standard date like this :

```
 public DateTime ConvertPeersianToEnglish(string persianDate)
        {
            string[] formats = { "yyyy/MM/dd" };
            DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(persianDate, formats,
                                              CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
            PersianCalendar persian_date = new PersianCalendar();
            DateTime dt = persian_date.ToDateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return dt;
        }
```

But these function just can handle this formats `1392/01/01` and of the users enter other formats i got this error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're specifying `MM` and `dd` in your format, which *require* two digits. Just specify `"yyyy/M/d"` as the format - that should handle both 1 and 2-digit day/month values. (You *can* specify multiple formats instead, but in this case you don't need to. You might want to *consider* doing that just to be clear, but `M` and `d` will both handle two digit values with a leading zero with no problems.

Note that if you're just specifying a single format, you don't need to put it in an array. You can just use:

```
string format = "yyyy/M/d";
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(persianDate, format,
                                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                  DateTimeStyles.None);
```

However:

- I suspect you want to specify the invariant culture, given that you don't want *this* value to affected by the culture
- Your current approach of converting a date to the Persian calendar will simply not work.

Currently you're implicitly *validating* that the date given is in the Gregorian calendar, but then you're *treating* it as a Persian date. For example, 1392/02/30 is a valid Persian date, but *not* a valid Gregorian date.

Instead, you should use a culture which already uses the Persian calendar, and then specify *that* as the culture in your `DateTime.ParseExact` call. Then you don't need to do anything else afterwards.

You might alternatively want to consider using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library - version 1.3 which includes the Persian calendar should be released in the next day or two.

Sample code using Noda Time:

```
var persian = CalendarSystem.GetPersianCalendar();
// The pattern takes the calendar system from the default value
var sampleDate = new LocalDate(1392, 1, 1, persian);
var pattern = LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy/M/d")
                              .WithTemplateValue(sampleDate);
var date = pattern.Parse("1392/02/30").Value;
Console.WriteLine(LocalDatePattern.IsoPattern.Format(date));
```

Comment: But sometimes my input format is like this 1392/01/01,can this(yyyy/M/d) handle this format?

Comment: @EA: Yes, it can. But please read my expanded answer - you've got bigger problems at the moment.

Comment: @user3613916: There's no need, because the one format will parse all the values.

Answer (score 2):

Specify all formats in `string[] formats`:

```
string[] formats = { "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/d", "yyyy/M/dd" };
```

Answer (score 1):

> But these function just can handle this formats 1392/01/01

Because your `yyyy/MM/dd` format only support this value.

If your input can be

```
1392/1/1
1392/01/01
1392/01/1
1392/1/01
```

values, you should provide all formats that support these in your `formats` array in your [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
string[] formats = { "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/M/dd", "yyyy/MM/d", "yyyy/M/dd" };
```

With these formats, if your value matches one of these formats, your parsing will be succeeded.

Comment: I think you meant to put `yyyy/M/d` as the first format - which will actually manage to parse all of these. There are bigger problems with the code though - see my answer.